# Capybara: match CSS that has a specific attribute without any value (e.g. matching <img alt>, but neither <img alt=""> nor <img alt="x">)

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, capybara

After updating Pandoc from v1.19 to 2.9, I need to refactor some of my specs.

Previously, this passed:

```
expect(page).to have_css '.figure img[src="decorative-image"][alt=""]'
```

Now it doesn't, as the produced HTML is not `<img alt="">` anymore, but `<img alt>`.

But I have now idea now, how to rewrite the CSS selector so it will match `<img alt>`, but neither `<img alt="">` nor `<img alt="x">`.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe this is possible with CSS/in a browser any more because not specifying a value for an attribute is the same as specifying an empty string – per https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/syntax.html#attributes-2:

> **Empty attribute syntax**  
> Just the attribute name. The value is implicitly the empty string.

Comment: Thank you. I meanwhile figured out that `[alt=""]` also captures an `alt` attribute without any value, so it still works for me.